# Creating a controlled Crack on glass vials and syringe

Tags: thermodynamics

I am working on a project that involves being able to detect defects on glass vials, and syringes using machine vision systems. I have the inspection system side of it complete, but am having a hard time creating these defects. I can create scratches, minor cosmetic defects on the containers, but I also want to create cracks. I tried tapping the container with a tungsten bit, but that didn't go that well. I am thinking of heating up the glass, then using a pipette to apply droplets of cold water onto the heated area. Or maybe something similar in reverse, using nitrogen to freeze the container, then using maybe a soldering iron to heat up a small spot? Looking for ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Well, what manufacturing process deviations do you expect to cause cracks?  That would be a starting point.   Or, given my experience with flame-treating glass, just grab a bunch of pipettes and hit them asymmetrically with a propane torch.  Statistically a few should generate stress cracks that you can use.

Comment: A lot of the cracks form from glass to glass contact when being put into trays, as well as other logistical handling of the containers. But, thank you for your input, i'll give that a try.